# Publish WTP project in Eclipse from Ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-wtp

Is there any way to have an Ant script running in Eclipse publish a WTP project? I want my ant script to perform some tasks, then kick off the publish as if I had done it from the UI, and then do some more things.

Comment: anything updated for this, I am also intersted in integrating WTP with existing builds.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how far you got with this.  But if you create  your own ant script, and put
 at the top, your script will get imported in the the WTP generated ant script.  That said, all i've gotten it to do is add the targets, I haven't quite figured out the "hooking in" to existing behaviour yet.

If you did find anything interesting, post it, as I'm looking for more info on integrating WTP with existing builds.